# biblatex: What's the first character of a field?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, formatting, conditionals, characters

I would like to know, what's the first character of the value of the editor field. If the character is a curly bracket "{" the value should be printed for example bold, if the first character is something else the fields value should be printed `\textnormal`.

I've tried to do that with the package xstring and the following code in a biblatex declaration:

```
\IfBeginWith{editor}{\{}{\textbf{\printfield{editor}}}{\printfield{editor}}
```

But this will not modify anything. How to do that right?

Comment: biblatex can do many different tests. Maybe any of those can be used to answer this question?

Comment: I've had taken a look to these tests, but didn't found the right one. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you should read up on data types in `biblatex`; `editor` is of the type name list, not field. Some details on how you can access data in a name list are described in the documentation on `\DeclareNameFormat`. You're on the right track in using `xstring`, but more care is required in passing arguments.

The code below will print out any corporate editor (i.e. any editor name enclosed in braces - see section 2.3.3 of the `biblatex` manual, version 1.4b) in boldface. I've applied edits to the generic `biblatex` format and macro definitions, but depending on the style you are using this solution will probably need to be adapted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareNameFormat{byeditor}{%  Based on first-last format from biblatex.def
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{ename:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{ename:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\newbibmacro*{ename:first-last}[4]{%  Basd on name:first-last macro from biblatex.def
    \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
    \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
    \ifblank{#2}{}{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
    \ifblank{#3}{}{%
        \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
        \ifpunctmark{'}
            {}
            {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
    \noexpandarg\StrRemoveBraces{#1}[\mycsnb]%
    \noexpandarg\StrFindGroup{#1}{1}[\mycsfg]%
    \ifblank{#2#3#4}
        {\ifdefstring{\mycsnb}{#1}
            {\mkbibnamelast{#1}}
            {\ifdefstring{\mycsfg}{#1}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{\mkbibnamelast{#1}}}}
        {\mkbibnamelast{#1}}\isdot
    \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{companion,
    author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
    title = {The LaTeX Companion},
    edition = {1},
    editor = {{Corporate Editor} and {A}ristotle and \texttt{HAL}},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    location = {Reading, Mass.},
    date = {1994}}
@Article{gillies,
    author = {Gillies, Alexander and {Corporate Author}},
    title = {Herder and the Preparation. Goethe's Idea of World Literature},
    journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
    volume = {9},
    date = {1933},
    editor = {Lastname, Firstname and {Corporate Editor} and {Corporation}},
    pages = {46--67}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes on the code:

- The corporate name gets passed to the last name argument (#1 throughout). All other name arguments (e.g. first names, name prefixes, etc.) are empty/blank.
- Enclosure in braces prevents `xstring` from doing any straightforward string comparisons. I've instead detected corporate names using some other commands from `xstring`.
- `\ifdefstring` tests if a control sequence is equal to a string. This test is from the `etoolbox` package, which is loaded by `biblatex`.

Comment: Wow! Thats much more complicated than I thought before! Thanks for your effort :-)

Comment: @Matthias If you compare my code with the definitions in `biblatex.def`, you'll see that I've only added a few lines. But yes, pattern matching isn't easy.